# Failed to execute 'execute' as Player_example

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying a command to ride the Ender Dragon in Minecraft Bedrock Edition 1.15.2, and my second command block, a chain command, says `Failed to execute 'execute' as Player_example.`

The command is: `/execute @a[tag=rider] ~~~ /execute @p ~~~ /tp @e[type=fishing_hook] ^^-2^-10`.

Comment: sorry I found out I just need to delete this

Comment: There should be a "delete" button below the question.